# Python Google Drive API Listing Files only lists 10 files

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a Python script that lists the files within a Google Drive folder using the Google Drive v3 API. As a first step, I have been trying to list all the files in my Drive. When testing this with the 'Try this API' feature on the Google API documentation page, it works, however, my Python script is only listing 10 files, and the nextPageToken is not being changed. This is the code I have written:

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(pageSize=1000,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

I have tried changing the pageSize to different values, but for some reason I can't get the script to list more than 10 files, where the 'Try It' feature within the Google API docs lists all my files.

Comment: If you set pageSize to a value smaller than 10, does it successfully fetch the next page?

Comment: I just tried setting the pageSize to 5, and I still got 10 files returned.

Comment: 10 in the same page?  Or did it successfully go to the next page?

Comment: Is there a good way to tell if the files are within the same page?

Comment: You could add a print statement at the top of your loop.

Comment: have you tried file.get('nextPageToken') and see whats actually in that.